# On mousedown+mouseenter, do this

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I've tried a few different methods of obtaining this, but I'm not having much luck with it.

**I want to, on `mouseenter`, check if `mousedown`, and if so, `selectit`.**

Basic structure: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZEZ4/1/

Attempt with "mouse state": http://jsfiddle.net/8ZEZ4/3/

For some reason it's always returning false, even when `down` should be `true`.

Anyone care to take a crack at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to change

```
$(document).on('mousedown',down=true)
$(document).on('mouseup',down=false)
```

to

```
$(document).on('mousedown',function(){down=true});
$(document).on('mouseup',function(){down=false});
```

and it'll work fine. You were being thrown an error on mousedown via the console in your original code. Always check the console for errors!

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZEZ4/5/

Comment: I swear that I tried that and it came back undefined. Any way to include the initial item?

Comment: Tried adding `.on('mousedown',selectit);` but it isn't registering that the mosue is down.

Comment: Nevermind. Added a `setTimeout` of 1ms to give the `down` a chance to register, fixed it right up. Thanks! **Final Code: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZEZ4/6/**